# Does Flatpak support command-line applications?

Tags: flatpak

I'm browsing [Flathub](https://flathub.org/apps). It contains thousands of apps, installable using Flatpak. All the apps on there seem to have a GUI. Are there any that are simple apps with a CLI (command-line interface)? Does Flatpak support CLI apps? If I wanted to publish a CLI app to Flathub, would that be accepted?

Comment: Can we assume that you have already read the "[App Requirements](https://github.com/flathub/flathub/wiki/App-Requirements)" document but that it is still unclear?

Comment: https://flathub.org/apps/details/io.github.paledega.alpine-rootfs seems like something that wouldn't have much of a GUI

Comment: It's true, a lot of CLI apps are missing from Flathub, but can be found on snap store. Really can't understand why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing in Flatpak stipulates that it only supports GUI applications.

In fact the tutorial offers to create a CLI application:

https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/first-build.html

As for the flathub [policy](https://discourse.flathub.org/t/flathub-needs-a-policy-about-command-line-tools/1855/6):

> It doesn’t mean CLI applications are forbidden on Flathub, but they need to be designated as console-applications or should not ship metainfo at all.

> For the record. we do **allow TUI applications with the type set to desktop-application as long as desktop launcher has Terminal=true**.

Comment: The problem with flatpak TUI apps is that commands locations are not appended to PATH env var,